# Specified cast is not valid. c# mdb database

Tags: c#, ms-access, null

I'm using mdb database with my c# application, I have table products which has 3 columns (Id,Name,Note), note column contain NULL values.

```
objConn.Open();
listView1.Items.Clear();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select prod_Id,prod_Name,prod_Note from products", objConn);
OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int i = 0;
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    listView1.Items.Add(dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());                 
    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.GetString(1).ToString());
    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.GetString(2).ToString());// Error appear here, which for Note column that has null values

    i++;
}
objConn.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your column contains NULL values then you cannot convert that NULL value to a string and try to add it to your listview subitems. You need to check for that

```
int i = 0;
while (dataReader.Read())
{
    listView1.Items.Add(dataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.GetString(1));
    listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(dataReader.IsDBNull(2) ? "": dataReader.GetString(2));

    i++;
}
```